# Amazon Simple Email Service - "From" email verification

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am signed up for AWS SES (with instance, S3 and my website running nicely). I also have rec'd approval for sending out email without receiver verification and "mass production" OK. The only thing I'm left with is having my 3 "from" email addresses verified. Started to download Perl, as was suggested to run email-verification scripts -- but got no where with the installation. Do have my credentials ready to use.

There is an AWS SES API to use for verification which I can't find... suspect that it has something to do with AWS's sdk which I could figure out how to install.

So my question: is there a simple, straight forward way to get my email addresses to Amazon for verification via a response email they send? Their documentation is somewhat confusing.

Comment: this is what AWS states:"To verify an email address, make an API call with the email address as a parameter. This API call will trigger a verification email, which will contain a link that you can click on to complete the verification process. " ...need to know how to make that API call. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to go validate your email address through their web service (like the perl script is doing).  You can also use their SDK's that they publish, which are wrappers around their web service. For example, if you have Visual Studio, you can use the [AWS SDK for .NET](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/) (also available as a Nuget package: PM> `Install-Package AWSSDKForNET`) and set up a simple console application to do something like this:

```
using Amazon.SimpleEmail;
using Amazon.SimpleEmail.Model;
static class Program {
  static void Main() {
    var client = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient("yourAccessKey", "yourSecretKey");
    var request = new VerifyEmailAddressRequest { EmailAddress = "yourEmailAddress" };
    client.VerifyEmailAddress(request);
  }
}
```

They also have SDK's available in [PHP](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/) and [Java](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/) that work pretty much the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but came up in a search.

You can now verify emails directly from the SES control panel  (See screen shot)

[AWS SES Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9G4J.png)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow. Please only post a solution as an answer; either expand your answer to include more information. For more information, please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.